# Calculate package latency when DPDK cycles overflow

Tags: dpdk

the following code used to calculate package latency:

```
TICK_PER_SECOND = rte_get_tsc_hz();

us_cycles = TICK_PER_SECOND / 1000 000;

register uint64_t received_cycles = rte_get_timer_cycles();

//sent_cycles will be recorded at somewhere
uint64_t latency = received_cycles > sent_cycles ? received_cycles - sent_cycles :
                       0xffffffffffffffff - sent_cycles + received_cycles;

uint64_t latency_us = latency / us_cycles
```

but sometimes latency_us will be a huge number like: 8384883669867977 us

is there some error calculation when the code handle cpu's cycles overflow?
should replace 0xffffffffffffffff with UINT64_MAX?

latency_us should be a normal value.

Comment: What was your reasoning behind that ternary calculation? Why not just `latency = received - sent`?

Comment: I think if cpu cycles overflow, received cycles will be smaller then send cycles., so i use the ternary calculation. Do you mean  just "received - send"  can also  handle this case？

Comment: Yes. Try a couple of sample cases. Suppose, for instance, that your counter was 8 bits, and a packet was sent at cycle 253 and received eight cycles later at cycle 5. What is the 8-bit unsigned result of 5-253?

Comment: Thank you. Sneftel. i try it and review subtraction for uint series. Perhaps the problem is not with calculation errors. i try to print received and sent cycles, like this:received_cycles:37510546898993433, sent_cycles: 37510546898993467. they are so closed. maybe there is some logci error in my code. anyway thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**rte_get_timer_cycles()** (uint64_t) has incremental values but surely it will overflow after some time (around every 2 hours depending on your cpu speed) and start from 0 when it reaches the value near UINT64_MAX. so,

```
uint64_t latency = received_cycles > sent_cycles ? received_cycles - sent_cycles : 
UINT64_MAX - sent_cycles + received_cycles;
```

should do just fine as you guessed